# How to access Serial Port which is opened in one form to another form

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

I have an application which has three forms one for login, after successful login user will be sent to select the comport and set the baud rate of the serial port after that they will be sent to the main application with the serial port which was configured in the previous form.

I don't know how am I supposed to access that serial port to another from. I am pretty new to C#

Here is my ComPort.cs

```
private void ComPort_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            comPort_comboBox.Items.AddRange(ports);
        }

        private void btn_open_port_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                serialPort1.PortName = comPort_comboBox.Text;
                string comportlabel= comPort_comboBox.Text;
                serialPort1.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(baud_rate_combobox.Text);
                string baudlabel = baud_rate_combobox.Text;
                serialPort1.Open();
                Home home = new Home();
                home.ShowDialog();
                
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Read(Data_rx, 0, serialPort1.BytesToRead);//.ToString();
            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(ShowData));
        }
```

I want to display the comport and baud rate like this
[image]
I created this application in single form so handling the serialport was not an issue but now the requirement is different I have three forms now.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for the reply let me try and apply this method for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities to solve your problem.

One could be changing `Home` form constructor like this

```
public Home(string portName, int baudRate)
```

and call it from your second form

```
Home home = new Home(
    comPort_comboBox.Text,
    Convert.ToInt32(baud_rate_combobox.Text));
```

With this you can manage serial port directly inside third form (so open the port inside it and set the event to receive data in it), without sharing its instance (can lead to other problems IMHO).

If you need serial port to be managed somehow even in the second form, then you can change third form constructor to pass that:

```
public Home(SerialPort serialPort)
```

and call it `Home home = new Home(serialPort1);`

Comment: I have edited my question can you please check it now and tell me what I need to do, I also have to handle the data received in Bytes as well

Comment: @Prashant are we supposed to write all the code for you? Second thing: we're answering your first question, if you have another one, please post another question.

Comment: @ Marco sorry about that, I have tried many methods none of them worked that is why I got anxious.

Comment: Did you try the methos shown in my answer?

Comment: Yeah I tried I am getting None as the value, maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Maybe I need to learn OOPS again I might be missing somethings.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can `save the serial port config` in `SerialPortConfig.cs` while you are in `SettingsForm.cs`,
2. `Read the serial port config` from `SerialPortConfig.cs` while you are in `MainForm.cs`

SerialPortConfig.cs

```
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace SerialPortNs
{
    public class SerialPortConfig
    {
        private static readonly SerialPortConfig _instance = new SerialPortConfig();

        private SerialPortConfig()
        {
            //
        }

        public static SerialPortConfig Instance()
        {
            return _instance;
        }

        public string? PortName { get; set; }
        public int BaudRate { get; set; }
        public Parity Parity { get; set; }
        public int DataBits { get; set; }
        public StopBits StopBits { get; set; }
        public Handshake Handshake { get; set; }
    }
}
```

SettingsForm.cs

```
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace SerialPortNs
{
    public partial class SettingsForm : Form
    {
        public SettingsForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // save serial port config
            SerialPortConfig config = SerialPortConfig.Instance();
            config.PortName = "COM1";
            config.BaudRate = 9600;
            config.Parity = Parity.None;
            config.DataBits = 8;
            config.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            config.Handshake = Handshake.None;

            // open MainForm
            Application.Run(new MainForm());
            
            // hide SettingsForm
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

MainForm.cs

```
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace SerialPortNs
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        private SerialPort _serialPort = new SerialPort();

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // read serial port config
            SerialPortConfig config = SerialPortConfig.Instance();
            _serialPort.PortName = config.PortName;
            _serialPort.BaudRate = config.BaudRate;
            _serialPort.Parity = config.Parity;
            _serialPort.DataBits = config.DataBits;
            _serialPort.StopBits = config.StopBits;
            _serialPort.Handshake = config.Handshake;

            if (_serialPort.IsOpen)
            {
                _serialPort.Close();
            }
            _serialPort.Open();
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
namespace SerialPortNs
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();

            // Open SettingsForm on startup
            Application.Run(new SettingsForm());
        }
    }
}
```